# UIActivityViewController - how to change the cancel button text

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

Does anybody know how to change the standard cancel button text value of UIActivityViewController?
By default it's "Cancel". But I want to change it e.g. to be in different language.

How to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. However, the Cancel button is localized by default.
Incidentally, you can create your own controller if that's what you want. And you can fill it with `UIActivity` objects. Note that when you look at that class, when the docs talk about an `activityController`, it's any `UIViewController`.

Comment: I don't want to create my own controller (but maybe will need to). Just want to change text for "Cancel" button and as you said, probably it's impossible :( Also when I'm changing localization settings - "Cancel" isn't changing, it's still "Cancel".

Comment: Now I see that I need to study more about... internationalization, not about changing text for UIActivityViewController. Thx.

Comment: And that's a vast subject... :)

Answer (score 3):

**Update: The code below only worked on iOS7.**

Like Rikkles said, you don't need to customise the text to make it localized. But just in case someone ever has a good reason to do this, here's the code:

```
NSArray *activityItems = @[@"Test"];

UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];

NSAttributedString *as = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Custom Text" attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor greenColor]}];
[[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIActivityViewController class], nil] setAttributedTitle:as forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

[image]

Comment: yep, because it looks like it's an UIAlertAction now. And it doesn't have appearance proxy

Answer (score 1):

As others point out, the button is localized by the system, you can't change it. At least on iOS 11. But I was struggling with that as well and the button kept its `Cancel` title even after changing the system language.

This post helped me to successfully localize the Cancel button of the share sheet and worked on a `UIDatePicker` in [countdown timer mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48063778/changing-locale-of-uidatepicker-in-countdown-timer-mode) that resisted previous system localization attempts as well: [Why UIActivityViewController doesn't display localized cancel string?](http://takeip.com/why-uiactivityviewcontroller-doesnt-display-localized-cancel-string.html)

Add this row into your `info.plist`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Cancel button will be localized. Also you can try [REActivityViewController](https://github.com/romaonthego/REActivityViewController)

Comment: Thx. My comment the same as for Rikkles.