# UIDatePicker CountDownMode Locale for hours and minutes

Tags: swift, localization, locale, uidatepicker

Iam using a UIDatePicker in the countDownMode. My app. supports english and german. Now i have translated all existing text and it is working fine. But the DatePicker in the countDownMode doesnt change. I have already seen on another post, that the localization does not has an impact on the countDown properties hours and minutes.
So hours and minutes still in english. I have tried this [Changing locale of UIDatePicker in Countdown Timer mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48063778/changing-locale-of-uidatepicker-in-countdown-timer-mode?noredirect=1&lq=1), adding "Localized resources can be mixed" and set it to yes, but it didnt helped.
It is really frustrating that a simple thing like that costs so much time..

By the way the language of my app is by default the language of the device, but if the user choose another language, it will change the app language while the device language is the same.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Are you sure you have set the locale of your device to German? Setting the picker locale doesn't affect the result https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48063778/changing-locale-of-uidatepicker-in-countdown-timer-mode?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment87363751_48338184

Comment: Thats the problem, if you change the locale of the picker, it will not change. But i wont change the device locale and i dont know if this is even possible, i dont think so?